# Angular Directive in dynamic kendo table column template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a dynamic kendo table that created on the angular controller,
the table is created after click event,
in some of the table columns there is angular directive.
the directive not compiled, the template not work,I get blank cell.
code:

```
   $("#grid" + index).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: context.param.url.GetData(),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                    function () {
                        return {
                            FromDate: obj.CalcDate,
                            ToDate: obj.CalcDate,

                        }
                    }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true
    },
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,

    columns: [

       {
           field: "AgregationProgramSum",
           title: resource["Productivity_Company_GridAgregationProgramSum"],
           template: "<div custom-directive=#: AgregationProgramSum # ></div>"
       },

    ]
    });
```

I see in the chorme debbuger that the values came well. bur the directive not happens

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for your directive?  You should only have to "use" your directive in the template of your grid.

Here is my directive:

```
     angular.module("KendoDemos")
        .directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      list: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</div>',

    replace: true,
    //require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

    }
  };
});
```

Here is my grid columns using directive:

```
                columns: [{
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Country",
                width: "120px",
                  hidden: true
                },{
                field: "City",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Title",
                  template:  "<my-directive data-list='paint'></my-directive>"

            }],
```

Here is working [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@DevQueen/OkAGUR).  Perhaps there is something wrong with your directive.  It is difficult to say with actually seeing your code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you of your answer, but my question is about dynamic template use' after the page compiled. for example: grid that draw only when button clicked. Thanks!!!!!